# Strange error with PHP: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php

Normally, this kind of error shows up when trying to perform a mysql_fetch_array to a query that's faulty, however I am constantly getting this error despite the query is being performed (it's an insert, I can check the new entrances in phpmyadmin).

For example, the output for this:

```
$query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO `objects` (`idObjects`, `obj_type`, `obj_name`, `obj_cdate`, `availability`, `status`, `User_idUser`) VALUES (NULL, '$type', 'EL TESTE', '$final', 'Public', 'Active', '13')");
$insert_place = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
if (!$insert_place) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
```

is 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\neo4play\factualimport.php on line 22
Invalid query:

with no error provided, and that row is still inserted into the database. Any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: Inserts don't return arrays, and you should not use `mysql_` functions in new development either.

Comment: Stop using mysql, it's deprecated and not secure. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fetch an INSERT query as it is not returning rows. You use mysql_fetch_array() with a SELECT statement to return an array of data from the query.
Take out:

```
$insert_place = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

and replace:

```
if (!$insert_place)
```

with:

```
if (!$query)
```